# MySQL pulling content from 2 tables that is connected by a third table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, outer-join

I currently have 2 tables in a database I need to get information from, "content" and "type".  These two tables are linked by a 3rd table name "typeMembers."  This is the structure:

```
Table Content:
id      content      link      date    isPublished
1       content 1    link 1    3/13/91  1
2       content 2    link 2    3/18/91  1
3       content 3    link 3    3/22/91  1

Table type:
id    name
1     Event
2     Page
3     Test

Table typeMember
id    type_id    content_id
1     1          1
2     2          1
3     3          1
4     1          2
5     1          3
```

Currently I have my query set up as:

```
//using PDO in PHP
q = $dbc->prepare(
    "SELECT a.id, a.content,a.date,a.link, c.name 
     FROM content a 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN typeMember b 
     ON b.content_id = a.id 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN types c 
     ON b.type_id = c.id  
     WHERE a.isPublished = 1 
     ORDER BY a.date DESC"
   );
$r = $q->execute();
```

When this is returned I am getting 1 row for each typeMember in the database instead of content.  What am I structuring wrong?

Data I would like to be returned:

```
id      content      link      date      name
1       content 1    link 1    3/13/91   Event, Page, Test
2       content 2    link 2    3/18/91   Event
3       content 3    link 3    3/22/91   Event
```

How it is being returned

```
id      content      link      date      name
1       content 1    link 1    3/13/91   Event
1       content 1    link 1    3/13/91   Page
1       content 1    link 1    3/13/91   Test
2       content 2    link 2    3/18/91   Event
3       content 3    link 3    3/22/91   Event
```

Edit: filing out the data actually made me realize what is going on.  There is a 1 to many relationship with content to type.  Is there a way to get all the types in one query?

Comment: Have you tried just using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are the same  ... eventually show  data sample , your actual result and the expected result

Comment: see [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899464) to maybe help out @scaisEdge or someone else :p

Comment: @scaisEdge Updated the data that is being returned as well as added example data.  The problem is it's a one to many relationship.  Can I return all types with one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for get the name in the same row you can use  group_Concat

```
SELECT  a.id, a.content, a.date, a.link, group_concat(c.name )
FROM content a 
LEFT  JOIN typeMember b ON b.content_id = a.id 
LEFT  JOIN types c ON b.type_id = c.id  
WHERE a.isPublished = 1 
Group by  a.id, a.content, a.date, a.link
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

Comment: When I do that it returns empty

Comment: @jppower175  adding distinct the query return empty ?

Comment: You rock. Perfect